# What do you mean by, "Please schedule a meeting by [date]"?

Tags: meaning, grammar

Should I schedule a meeting **ON** or **WITHIN** the specified date?

Comment: The question in the title is different to the one in the body. Please clarify what you want to know.

Comment: What's the difference between the title and the body? Apologies if I confused you as I am confused too about what's on the title meant too.

Comment: It seems to ask that the scheduling be done by [date]. It doesn't seem to say anything about what date the meeting will occur.

Comment: So, by "by [date]," do you mean that I should schedule the meeting on the specified date? I'm really sorry if  I'm having a hard time understanding it. English is not my primary language.

Comment: The sentences of this kind are also ambiguous as to whether the date specified is the date by which the scheduling is to take place (leaving it open that the meeting may then be scheduled for some later date) or the date by which the meeting itself is to take place. See [Schedule on Tuesday](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/30525), taking into account both answers, as well as the comments.