# Does the question "when did Alice tell you she would go?" ask about the date the plans were talked about or when she plans to go?

Tags: ambiguity, speech

Here is the situation:

Alice told Bob on Monday that she would go to the zoo on Friday.
Now, if I ask Bob: "Hey Bob, when did Alice tell you she would go to the zoo?"

Will Bob answer Monday or Friday?

If I want to get the other answer, how should I ask Bob?

Comment: Related: [Schedule on Tuesday](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/30525), [Pencil you in on/for Sunday evening?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/36477).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question is ambiguous, so Bob could legitimately answer either way.

I think most people would answer "Friday" because this is likely to be the more salient information. But it would depend on the context of your conversation with Bob -- if it's clear that you need to know when *he* learned when Alice would be going, he'd answer "Monday".

To get a particular answer you can ask:

> When will Alice be going to the zoo? -- Friday

> When did Alice tell you *that* she would be going to the zoo? -- Monday